# Strange question in a job-interview

Tags: personality

I would like to ask you the reasoning behind a question they asked me during a job interview (with a psychologist) a few years ago.

He basically handed me a bunch of colored cards (fifteen at least), asked me to think of my own logical order and to sort the cards according to the chosen order.

After I ordered them, he took notes on a sheet of my result, took the papers from me, shuffled them and gave them back to me, telling them to reposition them in the same order they had previously chosen.
And he added "70% of people change the order of at least one card in the second round".
It is clear that he only told me to influence me.

What is the purpose of this test?
I'm very curious.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. I am intrigued as to why you tagged this question as a personality question. What have you read regarding possible reasons for this test involving coloured cards? Is there something you read which indicates it is a personality test of some sort?

Comment: From your description it looks just as a memory test, but without knowing what the job, I can't say more. It's the moment before the test when it is time to ask what is its purpose. It's not necessary that the test on its own had a purpose but that the person who was testing you had his own purpose.

Comment: @Chris Rogers I tagged this topic as a personality question because it was a job interview with a Psychologist, to join in a bank. And they always do this type of job interview (at 1° step).

Comment: @Jan in light of what I wrote above, i'm quite sure that wasn't a memory a memory test.

Answer (score 1):

I mentioned in the comment that it could be just a memory test, but now, with knowing a bit more of the context (it was an interview to join a bank), it could be a test about how you stick with your first decision and how you are influenced by an *obvious suggestion*  to change it because, supposedly, "70% people before you did", so to *change the logic* by which you ordered the cards the first time.

It was one of the [aptitude tests](https://www.wikijob.co.uk/content/aptitude-tests/test-types/aptitude-tests), probably a variant of a [situational judgement test](https://www.wikijob.co.uk/content/aptitude-tests/test-types/situational-judgement-test).